# Magento 1.9 after setup website in localhost error message Controller file was loaded but class does not exist

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

My website is working fine but i have facing one error message during checkout process

In Var/report "Controller file was loaded but class does not exist" this type error message i have face so any one please provide appropriate guide

I have try to disable compilation and check but it's not working for me

So please tell me what is wrong

Thanks

Comment: please see this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202492/controller-file-was-loaded-but-class-does-not-exist/2203131#answer-2203131
hope it will helps

Comment: I have check so many answer but i can not able to fixed it.

Problem is only in localhost

Comment: the main point of that error is magento find your controller but you describe incorrect class name,  please see your Class name in your controller then make sure it same with the path folder, ex : if your controller file is placed in this path `app/code/Yourcompany/Yourmodule/controllers/IndexController.php` then the name in Class File  `IndexController.php` must be `Yourcompany_Yourmodule_IndexController()`

Comment: ok i will check and get back to you thanks for help